# Cloth simulation crinkles and goes through object?

Tags: modeling, animation, edit-mode, physics, cloth-simulation

So I want to create another blanket on top of the blanket I already made. This is what happens right now

[image]

When I look at the normals it looks like this, but I don't know if that matters or not

[image]

Comment: That’s normal. Cloth physics is a close approximation at best in my experience. I recommend you use a shrink wrap modifier with altered settings to move the second blanket outside the first.

Comment: Has the first blanket a collision modifier?

Comment: yes I added one but the top cloth still goes through it

Comment: And the collision modifier is below the cloth modifier, right?